# How does Spring framework guarantee that test code is not executed on production environment?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, production-environment

I have a simple SpringBoot application for sending emails. For security measurements  I want to know how does Spring Framework guarantee that test code is not executed on production environment. I couldn't find any explanation on internet for that only tutorials how to test Spring Boot applications.

Answer (score 2):

Spring doesn’t do anything to stop tests from being executed. The way you make sure tests don’t run in prod is: don’t deploy them to prod.

Your build/deploy process needs to make sure it excludes tests from the artifacts that get deployed. Put your tests under src/test and maven won't include them in the artifacts it builds (if you get around this by creating test jars, that makes it harder to keep the tests out of environments where they shouldn't be).

Answer (score 1):

If you use JUnit test for your test code and the unit test is in default folder src/test/java, it is not executed. Spring's ComponentScan does not search there for beans.

If you have some other kind of test code, which is written into your regular code, then you could use Spring Profiles to make sure it is not executed. But you should not mix your test code into your regular code, because that is a bad coding style.

Comment: Spring's ComponentScan does not know about source folders. It's the build process that makes sure classes from src/test/java are not in the classpath, so ComponentScan cannot see them.